# How to format full local date into simple mm/dd/yyyy?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

Need to format this date:

> `[Wed Jul 03 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
>   Thu Aug 01 2019 23:59:59 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)]`

Into simple `mm/dd/yyyy`, but **not with moment**. Cus moment is to heavy.

This is my format function which get array `date = [startDate, endDate]`

```
 formatDate = (date) => {
    const newDate = new Date(date);
    const dateFormatted = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < date.length; i++) {
      dateFormatted[i] = `${newDate.getMonth() + 1}/${newDate.getDate()}/${newDate.getFullYear()}`;
    }

    return dateFormatted;
  };
```

As result I am getting this `NaN/NaN/NaN`

Any suggestion, advice?

Comment: is date suppose to be executed as a function?  I see:  `date()` which doesnt quite make sense to me. Is it a function as the variable definition doesnt really give hint to the type, but at the same time another variable with the same name is an array.

Comment: No, that is spell mistake, thank you for asking : )

Comment: no problem. I will solve it for you, stand by

Comment: Is the date supposed to be displayed in html? Then you could use the date pipe. {{ myDateObj | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy' }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the result you want is something like:

```
`${d.getMonth().toString().padStart(2,'0')}/${d.getDate().toString().padStart(2,'0')}/${d.getFullYear()}`
```

So your function should be:

```
let formatDate = (date) => {
    let d = new Date(date)
    return `${d.getMonth().toString().padStart(2,'0')}/${d.getDate().toString().padStart(2,'0')}/${d.getFullYear()}`;
}
```

and then you can call it on a list of dates.

```
let dateList = [new Date(), new Date()]
formattedDates = dateList.map(formatDate)
```

You can also extend this to take a list of dates to process.

```
let formatDates = (dates) => dates.map(formatDate);
```

so you can also pass in a list of dates to process, leveraging the singular *formatDate*

Comment: That is solution, thank you very much! : )

Comment: No problem. Have a great day.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to not customize your `Date` variables it in that way,

You should define your `LOCALE_ID` which means that you don't need to use custom format for your `Date` (or currency, time etc.) variables. For example,

```
import { LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, {
  providers: [{provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'en-US' }]
});
```

Source: https://angular.io/api/core/LOCALE_ID#description

Answer (score 1):

Simple js function to convert `Date` object to string:

```js
const date = new Date();
function tommddyyyy(date) {
  return `${date.getMonth() + 1}/${date.getDate()}/${date.getFullYear()}`;
}
console.log(tommddyyyy(date));
```

Comment: Already try with that apporoch and as result get this: `NaN/NaN/NaN`

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Read my question again.

Answer (score 1):

The posted code doesn't produce `NaN/NaN/NaN`, it formats the date as m/d/y.

Your problem is here:

```
 for (let i = 0; i < date.length; i++)
```

The value of *date* is a string like "Wed Jul 03 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0200" with length 33, so you get 33 formatted dates. There are already many questions on parsing and formatting dates, so I'll mark this as a duplicate of those.

Answer (score 0):

angular has it's own formatDate function, I'd recommend using it:

```
import {formatDate} from '@angular/core';

formatDate(date, 'short', 'en-US');
```

1st arg is date or string, second is format (or shorthand format as used here), 3rd is the locale.

Comment: The question is tagged with Reactjs, not Angular.

Comment: @DanielBeck not when I answered it

Comment: I see what you mean. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

I expect date_arr to be an array of strings parsable as dates. Then I would use this plain javascript solution:

```
formatDate = (date_arr) => {
    return date_arr.map( dt => {
        // create an date object and convert to an iso-string (yyyy-mm-dd)
        var iso = new Date(dt).toISOString().substr(0,10);
        // rearrange the values as needed (mm-dd-yyyy)
        iso = `${iso.substr(5)}-${iso.substr(0,4)}`;
        // replace delimiter '-' with '/'
        return iso.replace(/-/g, '/');}
    );
};

// sample call
formatDate(['2019-05-03', new Date()]);

// ["05/03/2019", "07/18/2019"]
```

Comment: This changes the timezone, so will give the wrong date for the period of the timezone offset at the start or end of the day.

Comment: I think of only dates for this function (without time) so this should work as expected.